# What are "bad dreams" called and which verbs are associated with it in German?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

[Over at ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83898/can-nightmare-be-seen/83901#83901), I've opened a question about bad dream i.e. nightmares. English doesn't see a nightmare but it uses it with the verbs *have* and *be* (as in: *it **was** a nightmare*). I would like to know how it is used in German and with which verb it is associated?

> That project was a nightmare! We were over a year late and a million dollars over budget. (Das Projekt war ein Alptraum! Wir waren über ein Jahr zu spät und eine Million Dollar über dem Budget.)
>
> Last night I had a nightmare. (Letzte Nacht hatte ich einen Alptraum.)

Comment: In which language do you _see_ dreams/nightmares?

Comment: The ELL-Q currently is a HNQ.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu: Was ist ein HNQ? Hit'n'quit?

Comment: Man kann Phrasen (war ein Alptraum, hatte einen Alptraum), von denen man vermutet, dass sie gängig sind, übrigens bei Google ausprobieren, sehen wieviele Treffer sie provozieren und ein, zwei davon näher betrachten, um zu überprüfen, wie sie verwendet wurden.

Comment: Why do you use Alptraum, The Alps is a mountain,what is relationship between Alp and Traum?

Comment: @user sorry, Hot Network Questions.. the long inter-SE-list in the lower right.

Comment: _Alptraum_ ist eine alternative Schreibweise von _Albtraum_. Der Duden empfiehlt aber die Schreibweise mit _b_ (http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Albtraum)

Comment: @Dragut please don't use comments to ask new questions. Use new questions instead, please.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu Do we need all these acronyms? How about spelling things out?

Comment: @Martin *shrugs :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's like in English Language:

Last night I **had** a nightmare.

would be translated as:

> Letzte Nacht **hatte** ich einen Alptraum.

My relationship with Chuck **was** a nightmare.

would be translated as:

> Meine Beziehung mit Chuck **war** ein Alptraum.

If you had bad dreams you also could say:

> Ich habe schlecht geträumt.

This would be literally translated as:

> I dreamed bad.

But you wouldn't say "Ich habe einen Alptraum geträumt" instead you would use my last phrase "Ich habe schlecht geträumt."

Comment: Hey and welcome to the German Language StackExchange. If you want, you can take a look at the [tour] or browse around [help]. Have fun! :)

Comment: One thing that isn't *quite* the same is "*being in* a nightmare". Rather than "Ich bin wohl in einem Alptraum!", Germans more often say "Ich träume wohl schlecht!"

Answer (score 2):

In short:

100% identical to the English usage.

And longer:

If something *is* or *was* *ein Alptraum*, we do not mean the literal thing, but rather use it in a metaphorical sense.

> Das Projekt war ein Alptraum.

If you are talking about "having a bad dream" literally, use "haben".

> Gestern Nacht hatte ich einen Alptraum.

There is some sort of grey zone inbetween, expressed in the context, however:

> Nach meiner Fahrprüfung habe ich immer noch Alpträume.

That doesn't necessarily mean the preson is having bad dreams - But could be. English has this grey zone as well, however.